# Tilt window does not close properly

Tags: windows

Noise and cold are coming in from the street. Any idea how I could fix this? I was thinking of attaching something to the top to push the window to the frame, but not really sure what I could use for that.

The window has a closing mechanism on the top
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand how the system works. That lack of understanding severely limits the breadth of solutions I can offer.

Comment: I'm quite new to this but to me, it looks like the top locking mechanism locks into the middle of the frame. When I push the white part down it releases the frame and the window can be opened

Comment: is it your home, can you drill holes

Comment: Is there a handcrank that opens the window? Is there a release that allows the window to freely rotate down to an open position?  Is that little plastic/aluminum affordance at the top a latch release?

Comment: @popham the window can't be opened. It's tilt only. The second picture shows the open state. 
Yes, it's a top latch release

asinine, Yes, the home is mine. I can drill holes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the weatherstripping, or add some more.  It looks like your black pile (fuzzy) weatherstripping isn't working right.  You may need thicker, or just add some to the inside flange of the window panel.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip. I did not think of replacing the weatherstripping